# How to get file owner in AIX without munging ls output?

Tags: files, aix, stat

How might I *reliably* get the owner of a file in AIX?  By reliable, I don't want to parse the output of `ls`.  On Linux, I would just do a `stat --printf=%U foo`, but I'm working on AIX 6.1 and 7.1.  I know I can do `istat`, but as there is no `--printf` option on AIX `istat`, I would still have to munge the output with `grep` and `awk`, therefore not as desirable.  In other words, how can I emulate Linux's `stat --printf=%U foo` using only AIX's core utils?

Comment: Is `perl` or `tcl` available in core?

Comment: Yes, I have ``perl``, seems like it might be standard to have on AIX.  After tinkering around, I was able to get it with this one-liner ``/usr/bin/perl -e "print ((getpwuid((stat('foo'))[4]))[0]);"``.  It works, just not as pretty to write as Linux ``stat``.  I guess I'm really just playing code (script) golf.

Comment: I haven't seen a user-level interface to stat() in AIX; I ended up writing a perl script that emulates Linux's stat(1).

Comment: @JeffSchaller I would be interested to see this script. Does it emulate ``--printf`` and other nice Linux ``stat`` modes?  If it's not too huge, could you post as an Answer so I can upvote?

Comment: sure; I was just adding %U support to it, so it's a more-direct answer to your Q :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a script I wrote a while ago, in order to get a stat(1)-like utility in AIX. Just added %U! I found it more useful to use the -c option, which behaves slightly differently from --printf. Includes a handy-dandy local copy of perl's stat array as a comment block.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
# emulate GNU coreutils stat command in a limited way
# -- only implemented a subset of the stat() options

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
our $opt_c;

getopts('c:') or die "Usage: $0 [ -c (%n %i %u %g %s %U %X %Y %Z) ] file ...";
# default format is empty (not useful, but avoids 'undef' errors later)
$opt_c |= '';

for (@ARGV) {
  my @s = stat;
  next unless @s; # silently fail on to the next file
  my $p = $opt_c; # make a copy of the format string to mangle for each file

  # mangle and print
  $p =~ s/%n/$_/g;
  $p =~ s/%i/$s[1]/g;
  $p =~ s/%u/$s[4]/g;
  $p =~ s/%g/$s[5]/g;
  $p =~ s/%s/$s[7]/g;
  $p =~ s/%U/getpwuid($s[4])/eg;
  $p =~ s/%X/$s[8]/g;
  $p =~ s/%Y/$s[9]/g;
  $p =~ s/%Z/$s[10]/g;
  print "$p\n";

  #                 0 dev      device number of filesystem
  #                 1 ino      inode number
  #                 2 mode     file mode  (type and permissions)
  #                 3 nlink    number of (hard) links to the file
  #                 4 uid      numeric user ID of file's owner
  #                 5 gid      numeric group ID of file's owner
  #                 6 rdev     the device identifier (special files only)
  #                 7 size     total size of file, in bytes
  #                 8 atime    last access time in seconds since the epoch
  #                 9 mtime    last modify time in seconds since the epoch
  #                10 ctime    inode change time in seconds since the epoch (*)
  #                11 blksize  preferred block size for file system I/O
  #                12 blocks   actual number of blocks allocated

}
```

Comment: This seems a lot more involved than just using awk

Comment: It's certainly another script to have to carry around; I would rather have a perl script that's self-sufficient than count on IBM to be consistent with the formatting of its own (istat) command. Tough trade-off, particularly if perl isn't installed. If perl's not installed, then the [coreutils](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html) RPM probably isn't, either -- but would provide the `stat` command independently.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: There's [istat command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) as a stat() interface but sadly it doesn't provide any options, so no printf or anything useful.