# "ls" (or other) command to get the *complete* date time on AIX 7.1

Tags: files, ls, aix, timestamps

I’m looking for a command **on AIX 7.1** that can give me filenames,
size, and *complete* date/time (in a uniform format).

- `ls -l` and similar commands have the drawback that they give date
  (month and day) and time (hour and minute),
  if the file is not older than 6 months, and date and year otherwise. 
  (I want year, month, day, hour, minutes **and seconds** for all files.)
- The AIX version of `ls` does not support `--full-time`, reporting

  ```
  ls: Not a recognized flag: -
  ls: Not a recognized flag: -
  Usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRSabcdefgiklmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]
  ```

What command that exists on AIX will give me the full date/time,
in a consistent format, and the file size?

Comment: Does AIX have the `stat` command? Have you looked closely at the capabilities of ``find``?

Comment: If you don't have `stat`, you could just print it up with perl or similar.  Example: `perl -le 'print scalar localtime ((lstat "filename")[9])'`

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291183/117549

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, [istat](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) appears to solve your problem; from the man page:

```
$ istat /usr/bin/ksh

Inode 10360 on device 10/6    File
Protection: r-xr-xr-x
Owner: 2(bin)     Group: 2(bin)
Link count: 2     Length 372298 bytes

Last updated:  Wed May 13 14:08:13 1992
Last modified: Wed May 13 13:57:00 1992
Last accessed: Sun Jan 31 15:49:23 1993
```

... gives the file size and full timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Both istat and perl may be of help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo
rm -f f1
touch f1

echo
echo " With perl:"
perl -e '@d=localtime ((stat(shift))[9]); printf "%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $d[3],$d[4]+1,$d[5]+1900,$d[2],$d[1],$d[0]' f1

echo
echo " With istat:"
istat f1
```

producing:

```
$ ./s1


 With perl:
14-10-2017 14:26:01

 With istat:
Inode 1371634 on device 45/3    File
Protection: rw-r--r--   
Owner: 1296(drl)                Group: 100(usr)
Link count:   1         Length 0 bytes

Last updated:   Sat Oct 14 14:26:01 DFT 2017
Last modified:  Sat Oct 14 14:26:01 DFT 2017
Last accessed:  Sat Oct 14 14:26:01 DFT 2017
```

On a system like:

```
aix 7.1.0.0
istat - ( /usr/bin/istat, Aug 08 2010 )
perl 5.10.1
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

( With advice from http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/41325-command-get-file-timestamp-including-seconds-aix-5-3-a.html )